# Jquery Form Submit Validate URL

Tags: jquery, validation, url

I have included jquery file and following HTML

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" onSubmit="return validate();">
        <input type="text" required="true" name="URL" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When i submit form with empty field give the message "Please fill out the field" but if i write wrong URL i didn't find any message and form submit.

How can i do URL validation?

Comment: i have also added latest jquery file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please post the code in your `validate()` function. Also, you only need one version of jQuery.

Comment: You're looking for something like this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ ?

Comment: Dipak Thanks. My problem has been solved from your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : You are using type="text" ... So why would it give you error when you are entering wrong url. For that use doctype for HTML5 and mention your input as follows,

```
<input type="url" required="required" name="URL" />
```

2 : Please check your `validate()` function. You must `return false`, if it does not satify your condition, in order to stop the form being submitted.

Adding suggestion from Akki619...
You don't even need a single javascript for validation as HTML5 does everything for you. Find the awesomeness of HTML5 http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: just to add to dipak's answer here is the link for detail http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/